# wsadmin: jacl: AdminApp list <scope?> WebSphere 5.x

Tags: scripting, websphere, wsadmin, jacl

I am trying to list applications installed on particular server below command works fine on WAS 6.x and 7 however I cannot make the same on WAS 5.x

```
wsadmin> $AdminApp list /WebSphere:cell=cell01,node=node01,server=server1/
```

Also, $AdminApp help list does not show optional scope parameter.

Could you please advise ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way, however it's not the same output, it needs to be parsed to get the details.

```
wsadmin > $AdminControl queryName type=Application,node=node01,process=server1
```

In case there is another way please let me know.

Comment: Note that AdminControl only works in connected mode (when the server is running), but otherwise, this probably gives the data you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to v5 right now to test, but something like this might work:

```
proc listAppsByTarget {target} {
  global AdminApp
  set result []

  regsub -all / $target "" target
  foreach app [$AdminApp list] {
    foreach line [split [$AdminApp view $app -MapModulesToServers] "\r\n"] {
      if [regexp "^Server:  ${target}($|,)" $line] {
        lappend result $app
        break
      }
    }
  }

  return $result
}
```

This will print any application that has a module targetted to the specified server.  Used like this:

```
wsadmin>listAppsByServerTarget /WebSphere:cell=cell,node=node,server=server1/
DefaultApplication
```